# Facebook App, Site URL - Mobile App Content Not Found

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I recently got my access to publish_actions. Basically, having a site URL, will allow your users to be redirected to the site url when you click APP NAME

The issue is, **on browser, it would work** fine. But on Facebook Mobile APP, when you click on APP NAME, You will receive an error

[image: Mobile]

This Error will only happen when you try click on "APP NAME" on the facebook app, not browser.

[image: App Name]

[image: App Settings]

Is there any kind of setting that i missed out? & also , is there a name for that small text, I tried to google but can't find any relevant issues related to this.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever find a fix ?

Comment: It looks like you need to white list your app. Facebook disabled this feature because people were abusing it. The link to the form to request white listing is https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1051463851558493/ look at the top answer

Answer (score 1):

To enable opening an app from the notifications, you need to enable "Single Sign On" and "Deep Linking" in yor app Basic settings:

[image: Example]